Relative Localization in Euclidean Space via Pairwise Distance Matrix Optimization
Problem Statement: Tag Localization in a Room
We have a system of n tags moving inside a room. Each tag can estimate the pairwise distances between itself and every other tag. The goal is to determine the relative positions of these tags using only the distance measurements.
Given:

n tags in a room
A symmetric n × n distance matrix D, where $d_{ij}$ represents the distance between tag i and tag j, and $d_{ii}$ = 0

For example, with n = 4 tags, the distance matrix looks like this:
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & d_{12} & d_{13} & d_{14} \\
d_{21} & 0 & d_{23} & d_{24} \\
d_{31} & d_{32} & 0 & d_{34} \\
d_{41} & d_{42} & d_{43} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Questions:

Is it possible to determine the relative positions of tags 2, 3, ..., n with respect to tag 1, given only the distance measurements $d_{1j}$ for all j = 2, 3, ..., n?
What is the minimum number of tags n required to uniquely determine these relative positions?

Challenges:

Traditional multilateration approaches cannot be directly applied as the positions of reference points are unknown.
The problem seems to create a circular dependency, where tag positions are needed to determine distances, but distances are needed to determine positions.

My Possible Solution: Iterative Optimization Approach
To address this tag localization problem, we can employ an iterative optimization approach.
Solution Steps:

Initialize the system with a guess for the positions of all tags.
Define an error function that quantifies the difference between measured distances and distances calculated from the current position estimates.
Use an optimization algorithm to minimize this error function by adjusting the estimated positions.
Iterate until convergence or a satisfactory error threshold is reached.

Mathematical Formulation:
Let $\mathbf{p}_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i)$ be the position of tag i.
Define the error function:
$$
E = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n (||\mathbf{p}_i - \mathbf{p}_j|| - d_{ij})^2
$$
Where $||\mathbf{p}_i - \mathbf{p}_j||$ is the Euclidean distance between the estimated positions of tags i and j, and $d_{ij}$ is the measured distance between these tags.
The goal is to minimize E by adjusting the positions $\mathbf{p}_i$.
Implementation:

Start with random initial positions for all tags.
Use an optimization algorithm (e.g., gradient descent, Levenberg-Marquardt) to iteratively adjust the positions to minimize E.
Continue until the change in E between iterations is below a set threshold.

I think that is possible to solve the problem using the Ax=x equation, as is done in PageRank problem

Assuming $D$ does not have any missing entries, i.e. all tags are able to measure distance with all other tags, then you would need at least 4 tags to uniquely(!) determine the positions in 3D, up to rotation, translation and reflection. Note that these operations does not change $D$. If you want absolute coordinates, you need to "know" at least 4 of the positions to be used as anchors and calculate others from them.

If I want to know the relative position of all the tags relative to tag 1 how can I compute them if I don’t have their position?

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\op{\operatorname}
\def\rank#1{\op{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Given a matrix wherein each column represents a $3\rm D$ position vector
$$\eqalign{
X &= \left[\matrix{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n}\right]&\in \bbR{3\times n} \\
}$$
create a new matrix by subtracting $x_\o$ from each column of $X$
and calculate its Gram matrix
$$\eqalign{
Z &= \left[\matrix{0&(x_2-x_\o)&\ldots&(x_n-x_\o)}\right]\in\bbR{3\times n}\\
G &= Z^TZ\,\in\bbR{n\times n},\qquad \rank G=3 \\
}$$
Calculate the Eigenvalue Decomposition of $G$
(since $G$ is rank deficient, only 3 of the eigenvalues will be non-zero)
$$\eqalign{
G &= USU^T \\
}$$
Drop the zero eigenvalues $S\to{\bar S}$ and the corresponding columns of $U\to{\bar U}$
and use the reduced matrices to calculate
$$\eqalign{
{\bar W} &= {\bar S}^{1/2}{\bar U}^T \\
  &= \left[\matrix{0&{\bar w}_2&{\bar w}_3&\ldots&{\bar w}_n}\right]
  \in \bbR{3\times n} \\
G &= {\bar W}^T{\bar W} \\
}$$
Add a random vector $(w_\o)$ to each column of $\bar W$
$$\eqalign{
W &= \left[\matrix{w_\o&w_2&w_3&\ldots&w_n}\right] \\
}$$
Although the columns of $W$ and $X$ are all different
$\LR{{\rm i.e.}\;w_k\ne x_k},\,$
the $D$ matrix of $W$ is identical to that of $X.\;$
This means that you cannot expect a unique solution to the inverse distance problem.
However, it is easy to calculate a solution to the problem because the Gram matrix can be calculated directly from knowledge of the Distance matrix alone
$$\eqalign{
A &= D\h D \qquad \{ {\sf Hadamard\ Product} \} \\
G_{jk} &= \tfrac12\LR{A_{j\o} + A_{\o k} - A_{jk}} \\
}$$
As others have noted, translating and/or rotating the columns of the $W$ matrix does not change the $D$ matrix, so you can generate a whole family of solutions from this one basic solution.
It is also worth noting that permuting the order of the eigenvalues on the diagonal of $\bar S$ (and the corresponding columns in $\bar U$) will generate a different $\bar W$ matrix. Such permutations yield a total of $6=3!$ basic solutions to consider.

I'm curious, can you explain why this method works?

It's based on the following relationships
$$\eqalign{
&G = Z^TZ, && G_{j1}=0,\quad G_{1k}=0 \
&|z_j-z_k|^2    ;&=; &|z_j|^2 + |z_k|^2 - 2z_j^Tz_k \
&(D\odot D){jk} &= &G{jj} + G_{kk} - 2G_{jk} ;=; A_{jk} \
}$$

Brilliant! I would like to add that $QW$ is also a solution for any orthogonal $Q$.

What do you think of the error function defined in the question? Is this solution also a minimizer of the error function in case of noisy distance measurements?

For a distance metric other than Euclidean, you must resort to an optimization procedure like the one you described.  But the presence of the Gram matrix should produce a least-squares solution for noisy data. You should try using my method as the initial guess for your optimizer and see what happens.

Where can I find the result? Are the columns of vector W the solution? I want to ask you another follow-up question m: how does the problem change if I know the z of all the points?

The method you described is probably the best method to tackle this problem, as it is also robust to measurement errors. However, consider the following construction method for gaining intuition.

Select $p_1=(0,0,0)$.
Select $p_2=(d_{12},0,0)$. Note that any selection of length $d_{12}$ vector is a valid choice and you cannot distinguish between them.
Draw the sphere of center $p_1$ and radius $d_{13}$. Also, draw the sphere of center $p_2$ and radius $d_{23}$. This will give the possible locations of $p_3$ as a circle. Again, all points are valid solutions and there is no way of distinguishing them. So, select one with $z=0$.
Similarly, draw the sphere of centers $p_1, p_2, p_3$ with radiuses $d_{14},d_{24},d_{34}$ respectively. They should intersect at a single point, which is defined as $p_4$.
Now, you created anchor points for others to take reference from. Note that this 3D object can be rotated freely around $p_1$ and any resulting coordinates would be a valid solution.
For remaining points, repeat step 4.

This method is actually easy to implement but it cannot work if the measurements are noisy. Your method would probably give some random approximate solution from the infinitely many solutions.
